# How to use XmlStarlet with conditionals?

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

### Source XML

```
<xml>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">92346523</element>
        <element name="bar">true</element>
    </block>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">89753298</element>
        <element name="bar">true</element>
    </block>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">67897324</element>
        <element name="bar">false</element>
    </block>
</xml>
```

I would like to update the value of every `<element name="bar">true</element>` to the value of the `<element name="foo">` in the same `<block>` with a Linux shell script using XmlStarlet. Is it possible with a single [`xml ed`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) command?

### Expected result

```
<xml>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">92346523</element>
        <element name="bar">92346523</element>
    </block>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">89753298</element>
        <element name="bar">89753298</element>
    </block>
    <block>
        <element name="foo">67897324</element>
        <element name="bar">false</element>
    </block>
</xml>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with bash please consider removing that tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one `<element name="foo">` in the `<block>`, the following should work:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//element[@name="bar" and text()="true"]' \
              -x '../element[@name="foo"]/text()'
```

Comment: I think that should be `-x '../element[@name="foo"]/text()'`.

Comment: And the reference noted that "-x is not implemented yet"…

Comment: @konsolebox It works without the `text()`. What's the difference?

Comment: @konsolebox Interesting, XmlStarlet 1.3.1 (libxml2 2.7.8, linked with 20900; libxslt 1.1.26, linked with 10127) outputs the "expected result" for both expressions. Thanks!

Comment: @konsolebox: Yeah, I think you're right, at least with newer versions of xmlstarlet. According to http://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/code/ci/master/tree/NEWS that change was made in 1.4.0. Gergõ: The documentation for xmlstarlet is really lagging; it's a great tool but it needs some help.